# Qt Sqlite table column appears to be gone

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, qt4

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
db.setDatabaseName(":temp:");

if (!db.open()) {
    qDebug() << "Database open error." << db.lastError();
    return;
}

QSqlQuery query(db);
query.prepare("create table if not exists dew (id int, title varchar(255) not null)");
if (!query.exec()) {
    qDebug() << "Query exec error. " << query.lastError();
    return;
}
qDebug() << "Insert query exec OK";

if (!query.exec("insert into dew(id, title) values (1, 'hello')")) qDebug() << query.lastError();
```

Shows the output as

```
Insert query exec OK 
QSqlError(1, "Unable to execute statement", "table dew has no column named id") 
Insertion finished.
```

Table creation seems to be OK. But where is **id** field? I'm confused with this code. I test     **query.record().contains("id");** and it is **false**

Comment: If, before you run that code, a table named `dew` exists _without_ an `id` column, that table won't be changed. Did you check?

Comment: Well! You guessed right! But another thing, :temp: should suppossed to be deleted after the exec finishes. But it stays.

Comment: Where did you read that?

Comment: The Book of Qt 4 - The Art of Building Qt Applications [Daniel Molekentin]. 'After the exec finishes' - I meant after the QApplication::exec() finished :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`":temp:"` is not a valid name for a temporary database, this creates a regular database on disk which stays after the database connection is closed.

To create a temporary or an in-memory sqlite database, that won't be saved to a file, you need to pass respectively an empty string (*) or the special string `":memory:"` as the database name.

http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html

<sub>Qt doesn't allow an empty `QString` as the database name, but a `QString` starting with a `'\0'` should work: `db.setDatabaseName(QChar(0));`</sub>